# Permission Denied when trying to create a folder on Amazon EFS

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, aws-lambda, amazon-efs

I'm trying to create a folder on EFS from inside a .NET Core 3.1 Lambda function.
The error is:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/mnt/root/Sub1/Sub2' is denied.
```

In this case both the Sub1 and Sub2 folder don't exist.

The Lambda is connected with a EFS Access Point to the /root folder on the file system.
The Access point has user, owner and group ids set to 1001 and permissions to 0777.

The Lambda function reads files from a different pre-existing folder just fine but can't create a new folder.

Edit: The relevant C# code is:

```cs
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(Vars.EFSLocation, _guid));
if (!dir.Exists)
  Directory.CreateDirectory(dir.FullName);
```

The `Vars.EFSLocation` is e.g. `/mnt/root/Sub1`, where the Sub1 folder does not yet exist.

Comment: Show us your code, pls.

Comment: I've edited the question and added the code